# WriteToFile Not Writing File in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

**UPDATE**

Whenever I comment out these lines writeToFile will create a file but if I dont,it will not work.

Here is my code..

```
   NSMutableDictionary *allData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSArray *countries = [self retrieveCountries];

for(NSDictionary *dicCountry in countries){
    NSString *countryName = [dicCountry objectForKey:@"en_name"];

    NSArray *capital = [self retrieveCapitals:countryName];

    NSMutableDictionary *capitalInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for(NSDictionary *dictPerCap in capital){
        NSString *cap = [dictPerCap objectForKey:@"en_name"];
        NSArray *items = [self retrieveItems:cap];
        NSArray *categories = [self retrieveCategories:cap];

        if(items == nil)
            items = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        if(categories == nil)
            categories = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        // store data in a dictionary
        NSDictionary* tempCapDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    items, @"items",
                                    categories, @"categories",
                                    nil];

        //store
        [capitalInfo setObject:tempCapDic forKey:cap];
    }

    // store data in a dictionary
    NSDictionary* dataDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             capital, @"capitals",
                             capitalInfo, @"info",
                             nil];

    //store
    [allData setObject:dataDic forKey:countryName];
}

/**************************/

NSDictionary *rootDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:countries, @"detailedCountries", allData, @"all", nil];
```

The lines that needs to be commented out inorder to work are:

```
capital, @"capitals",
capitalInfo, @"info",
```

in NSDictionary* tempCapDic.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Where is writing to disc code ?

Comment: Log the contents of whatever you call `writeToFile` on and add it to the question.

Comment: @wain: okay. will try to check its log.
thanks for sparing your time to my question...

Comment: You need add:    [allData writeToFile:pathtoplist.plist atomically:YES]; after    [allData setObject:dataDic forKey:countryName];

Comment: @basheer: already edited my question.
thanks for sparing your time to my question...

Comment: is your plist's path on the documents directory ?

Comment: @basheer: yes. before, i was able to create a file but then i changed my flow in my dictionary and then it already produced unsuccessful creation of file.

Comment: Not all dictionaries can be written, only dictionaries that only contain instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary. any child NSDictionarys must also conform the the previous types. Also allow are other objects that conform to NSCoding.

Comment: @CokePokes: allData from the top most code is an nsmutabledictionary in a method while allData from the bottom most code is a nsdictionary. both variables have different functionality. blame it to the previous programmer.

Comment: @Zaph: my plist structure is like this..

nsdictionary has:
1. nsarray has
 a. objects
2. nsdictionary has
 a. nsdictionary has
   I. - III. nsarray(3)

Comment: firstly you set atomically:YES in your code it's NO and check whether your dictionry content a null value in any of its index if content then it can't be write.

Comment: @iMove it is not possible to have any elements that are nil in an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @Zaph Why it is not possible if you inserting nil string with key pair then it may be.

Comment: You can insert an empty string, that is not nil. NSDictionaries do not allow nil objects as either keys or values. From the Apple documentation: "Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull." This applies to almost all Foundation collections. Try it.

Comment: i think your idea is right @Zaph but then NSNull is not a valid keyword. am trying your idea because you do have some point and i found out that i have a nil value in my nsdictionary but then NSNull is not valid in my xcode.

Comment: right got it sorry for being stupid right here. i will inform you the outcome for this. thanks everyone for sparing your efforts! God speed!

Comment: `NSNull` is a class not a keyword. An instance is created with `[NSNull null]`. Example: `NSDictionary *d = @{@"key" : [NSNull null]};`